# Need Help in Securing User Submited SWF Files on Server

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, security

I'm making a site that will allow people to upload .SWF files to my server. Before I do, what type of security measures should I take to prevent my site from being compromised?

I looked at some source code from other sites and came to the conclusion that I should set scriptaccess to never if I choose to embed the swf file, and/or upload it to a different domain from my main site.

But after looking at the source code from other sites (newgrounds.com, deviantart.com, dagobah.net), it looks like some of them are either embedding User SWF files within another SWF file of the own, similar to a sandbox enviroment, and/or putting it inside an iFrame or just embedding the SWF object without the scriptaccess property defined.

Is that all there is to securing user submited SWF files? And how exactly does the SWF sandbox work? Are there any special sanitation codes inside it? Was I even right in my security analysis with the websites I mentioned?